# Joomla using DISTINCT in mySQL call

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I'm trying to use DISTINCT to get a list of cities from a column in my DB.

```
function cityData() {
    $db =& JFactory::getDBO();
    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT MSTCITY FROM " . $db->nameQuote('#__mls') . " ORDER BY MSTCITY;";
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $tbl = $db->loadObjectList();
    return $tbl;
}
```

Is there something akin to `loadObjectList()` that I can use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several options available to get data using database object.
You can check this link- http://docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_database_using_JDatabase/1.5

In your case you can use `loadResultArray()` in place of `loadObjectList`.It'll return list of cities as values of an array.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the revised joomla resource page for version 2.5 and 3.x 
[Selecting data using JDatabase](https://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase). Also since you're already using the *loadObjectList()* function this question may be better asked as

> How to use DISTINCT and JDatabase together

[This post](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=783135) has a good solution by *Janga_Jack* but for your example here's a Joomla 3.x way to accomplish what you need, that allows you to use the convenience methods `quote()` or `q()`, `quoteName()` or `qn()`, and especially `escape()` or `e()`.

```
function cityData() {
    $db =& JFactory::getDBO();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);

    $fieldlist = $db->qn(array('mls.MSTCITY')); // add the field names to an array
    $fieldlist[0] = 'distinct ' . $fieldlist[0]; //prepend the distinct keyword to the first field name  

    $query->select($fieldlist);
        ->from($db->qn('#__mls', 'mls'))
        ->order($db->qn('mls.MSTCITY'));

    $db->setQuery($query);
    $tbl = $db->loadObjectList();
    return $tbl;
}
```